# An open and closed set

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces, rational-numbers

Provide an example of a **non-empty** subset $X \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$ that is both open and closed, and justify your example.

This is a question from a practice set I have. The first and foremost thing I would check is the empty set $\emptyset$ and the rationals $\mathbb{Q}$. But $X$ needs to be non-empty and $\mathbb{Q}$ is neither open nor closed. I then considered a slightly less trivial example: $(2, 3) \cup (4, 5)$ with the metric $d(a, b) = |a - b|$ (I think, $(2, 3)$ and $(4, 5)$ are both open and closed but I am not sure how to justify it).

Any assistance in finding and/or justifying such a set is much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you say $\mathbb{Q}$ is neither open nor closed?

Comment: Are you talking about sets which are open or closed subsets of $\Bbb Q$? Or of $\Bbb R$?

Comment: @aschepler I recall reading it somewhere. Also check my previous post (though that one is in $\mathbb{R}$...)

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I think it is $\mathbb{Q}$ based on the question?

Comment: Then $\Bbb Q$ is both a closed subset and an open subset of $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos How would you justify this?

Comment: Because this is true for *every* metric space (and, more generally, for every topological space).

Comment: Which definition of "open" and "closed" are you working with? In any case, it's important to note open or closed is not just a property of a set - it's a property of a set with respect to some topology. So "open in $\mathbb{Q}$" is different from "open in $\mathbb{R}$". And those actually mean "open in the standard topology on $\mathbb{Q}$" or "open in the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$", but that part can be left implied when there's no ambiguity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In every topological space $X$ the empty set $\emptyset$ and the whole $X$ are always [clopen sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clopen_set), i.e. sets that are simultaneously open and closed. Since your question asks about a non-empty example, we can use $\mathbb{Q}$. A more interesting clopen subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ (with the usual topology) is $(-\pi, \pi)$. It is immediate that the interval is open. It is also closed, because its complement $(-\infty, -\pi) \cup (\pi, +\infty)$ is open.

Comment: I see. If we treat $\mathbb{Q}$ as a metric space then, what would be the metric for it to be both open and closed? Sorry, I am quite new to metrics.

Comment: The usual one, i.e. $d(a, b) = |a - b|$. This metric induces the topology generated by open intervals which I referred to as "the usual topology".

Comment: Okay. Again, I am not all too familiar with topology. Thank you.

Comment: To be precise, the "usual" topology on $\Bbb Q$ is the subspace topology inherited as a subspace of $\Bbb R$, which means its basis is the intersection of open (in $\Bbb R$) intervals with $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: I'd prefer the interval $(e,\pi)$. ;-)